# could not find function 'fluidRow'/'fixedRow'

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a shiny app on the Red Hat Linux Server. My app is loading on the server, but gives an error 'could not find function fluidRow'. I called library(shiny) also, while it is not required as I am running app on shiny server. I am using fluidRow few places in my code.

```
         tabPanel('Tab 1', h5("Tab Summary"), 
                  fluidRow(showOutput("nChart","nvd3")), 
                  fluidRow(chartOutput("Chart1")),
                  fluidRow(chartOutput("Chart2")),
                  fluidRow(showOutput("Table1","datatables"))  
                  ),
```

I also changed it to 'fixedRow', it does not work either.

Comment: I recently installed shiny-server-0.4.0.15-x86_64.rpm

Comment: I removed the older version and installed shiny-server-1.0.0.42-x86_64.rpm, but still getting the same error.

Comment: How can I check the version of shiny-server?

Comment: I think this is more likely to be an issue with the version of the shiny package

Comment: I am struck with this error, uninstalled using `sudo yum remove shiny-server` and installed using `sudo yum install shiny-server-1.0.0.42-x86_64.rpm`. Also tried, `sudo yum update shiny-server`
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: Also installed package shiny again using `sudo /usr/bin/R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"`

Comment: I found the answer here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Shiny-Application-Layout-Guide, it says, "Note that the functions described here require the development version of the Shiny package. You can install this version as follows:"

`devtools::install_github("shiny", "rstudio")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from this link
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Shiny-Application-Layout-Guide

Note that the functions described here require the development version of the Shiny package. You can install this version as follows:

```
devtools::install_github("shiny", "rstudio")
```

Thanks @hadley